# How to show that an unknown function $f(x)$ has a root in an interval $[0,a]$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

If $f:  \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $a>0$ and $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx = 0$, how can I show or prove that $f$ has a root in $[0,a]$?

Comment: I suppose $f$ is continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is not continuous, there isn't necessarily a root (it is easy to draw a counterexample; make a sketch).

If $f$ is continuous, the [Mean Value Theorem (for integrals)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Proof_of_the_First_Mean_Value_Theorem_for_Definite_Integrals) says there exists a $c \in (0,a)$ such that:
$$\int_0^a f(x) \,\mbox{d}x = f(c)(a-0) = f(c)a$$
If $a>0$, this can only be $0$ if $f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is not continuous, the function defined as $\frac{|2x-a|}{2x-a}$ when $x\neq \frac{a}{2}$ and $1$ when $x = \frac{a}{2}$   would be a counter example.

If we assume $f$ is continuous, using MVT we can find some $0<c<a$ where $f(c)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to prove that $f$ has a root between $[a,b]$ is

1) Assume $\int f(x)dx=F(x)$ and $f$ is contineous and differentiable in $[0,a]$(otherwise it's not necessary that there will be a root)

2) Then we can say $F(a)=F(0)$  (from $\int_{0}^a f(x)=0$)
Now if $f$ is contineous and differentiable , $F$ will be contineous and differentiable and $F(a)=F(0)$, then by rolle's theoram,
it can be said that there exist a c such that $F'(c)=0$ for $c\in[0,a]$ which is same as $f(c)=0$

Answer (score 0):

If you take $f(x) =1$ when $0\le x\le a/2$, and $f(x) =1$ when $1\ge x > a/2$, you have a counterexample. Continuity is an essential ingredient.

Suppose $f$ has no root and is continuous. It is either positive or negative. Without loss of generality, you can suppose $f$ is positive. If not, you can take $-f$, this does not change the $0$ integral nor the property of having roots or not.

By continuity, given for instance $\epsilon = f(0)/2 >0$, there exists $\eta>0$ such that  for all $x < \eta$, $|f(x)-f(0)|< \epsilon$. So $\int_0^af(x)dx = \int_0^\eta f(x)dx + \int_\eta^a f(x)dx \ge \int_0^\eta f(x)dx > \eta f(0)/2 $.

The  hypothesis that $f$ has no root leads to a false consequence. Hence $f$ has a root on $[0,a]$.